# MPAndroid line chart expanding if values on x-axis is in large size

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroid library for representing line and pie chart. When I use small values like 1,2,3,4.. at x-axis, The chart fit in screen and there is no need of scroll. But when data for x axis is large like date range (13-04-2016), So it gives me only 5 values instead of 10 on screen and when I zoom the chart then it shows all values in horizontal scroll. using below code

```
 private void initializeChart(LineChart chart) {
    // Chart view
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    chart.setDescription("");
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(true);
    chart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setTextColor(color); // left y-axis
    chart.getXAxis().setTextColor(color);
    //X axis
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);

    //Y axis
    YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
    YAxis rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setDrawLabels(false);
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    leftAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    ChartItem item = CannonJsonParser.parseCanonJson(act, act.res);

    setLineData(10, 20, item);
    // set data
    chart.setData(lineData);
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    //animate
    // chart.animateX(2000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuart);
    chart.setDragEnabled(true);
    chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    chart.setScaleXEnabled(true);
    chart.setScaleYEnabled(false);
    chart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(false);
    chart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false);
}
```

I want that either all data should be fixed on a single screen without scroll or if it scrolls then it should be scrollable without zooming graph. Right now when I zoom in the graph then only it scrolls and shows all data.

Answer (score 0):

set AxisMaxValue(). It will show proper graph.

```
chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(float);
```